# How SpringSource Toolsuite start its tc instance?

Tags: sts-springsourcetoolsuite, tcserver

What in hell happened under the hood, if I click the green 'Start the Server' button within the STS servers view ? I thought, the underlying CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh is started, but it seems thats not the case. I can comment the line starting the java process for 'start' (and 'run' too) in catalina.sh, but the tc is started nevertheless. The lauch configuration panel is also not very helpful: there are only program arguments (here 'start') and VM arguments (multiple -Dsomething... values) but no executable file, jar or similar. Can somebody enlighting me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TC Server from STS is launched in pretty much the same manner as Tomcat from regular Eclipse J2EE IDE (using WTP). The server is started using `bootstrap.jar`. You can find it in *ClassPath* tab of your launch configuration.

The *start* parameter mentioned is used as a arg for `main` method of `Bootstrap` class located inside `bootstrap.jar`